# my code keeps showing syntax error in my elif/else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to make a basic pig latin translator but the editor keeps showing me a syntax error.

```py
ay = "ay"

way = "way"

consonants = ("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")

vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

user_word = input("Enter your word here: ")

first_letter = user_word[0]

first_letter = str(first_letter)

first_letter = first_letter.upper()

if first_letter in consonants:

        print(first_letter + "is a consonant.")

remove_first_letter = user_word[1:]

pig_latin = remove_first_letter + first_letter + ay

print("The word in Pig Latin is " + pig_latin)

elif first_letter in vowels:

        print(first_letter + "is a vowel.")

pig_latin = user_word + way

print("The word in Pig Latin is " + pig_latin)

else:

        print("I don\'t know what" + first_letter + "is.")
```

This is what i have come up with.
The exact error message that it shows is:

```py
File "<ipython-input-33-8e1536233f19>", line 14

    elif first_letter in vowels:

       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The indentation is invalid. Please fix and thanks (you can't have an `elif` just hanging out without an associated `if`).

Comment: when i used the indentation, it showed indentation error, so instead i just removed indentation. Before the elif statement, the code is running fine with the if statement. after the elif statement, its throwing an error (?)

Comment: The `if` is syntactically valid and its block ends and the outer main scope resumes. But then, out of nowhere, there's an `elif` without an `if` before it. A [mcve] of this error is the following program (run it for yourself): `elif True: print("hello world")`.

Answer (score 3):

Python is an indentation-dependent language. `elif` and `else` need to be at the same depth as `if`, and whatever statement depends on the condition needs to be indented further.

For example:

```
if first_letter in consonants:
    print(first_letter + "is a consonant.")
    remove_first_letter = user_word[1:]
    pig_latin = remove_first_letter + first_letter + ay
    print("The word in Pig Latin is " + pig_latin)
elif first_letter in vowels:
    print(first_letter + "is a vowel.")
    pig_latin = user_word + way
    print("The word in Pig Latin is " + pig_latin)
else:
    print("I don\'t know what" + first_letter + "is.")
```